# how to write the cmakelist for multi-static library in same parent

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm newer to the cmake, I'm currently working with the project that builded with cmake, I'm now known how to write the cmakelist for static library.Nonetheless,  I cannot know how to write cmakelist for the following section:

```
|---TopLevel
|--->StaticLib
|----->CMakeLists.txt              #1
|----->LIB1
|------->myadd.h
|------->myadd.cpp
|------->CMakeLists.txt
|----->LIB2
|------->mysub.h
|------->mysub.cpp
|------->CMakeLists.txt
|---main.cpp
|--->CMakeLists
```

I'm know how to write all cmakelists other than the comment #1(I'm not definitely insure that these cmakelists I wrote are prefertly proper).

Additional, there are some functionals in Lib1 were used in Lib2. When I attemp to include the mysub.h in main, the compiler give the warning cannot open myadd.h, how to resolve this problem.

```
//in mysub.h
```

#ifndef **MY_SUB__HPP**
#define **MY_SUB__HPP**

include "myadd.h"

#endif

thanks everyone

Comment: What trouble are you having writing the `CMakeLists.txt`?  If you know how to create static libraries, you just do that.  Something akin to `add_library(lib1 STATIC a.cpp b.cpp ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

By using `add_subdirectory(<subdirectoryName>)`, with `CMakeLists.txt` in those subdirectories defining their own targets.

Sorry that I am with no enough reputation to put it as a comment, which I think is more suitable.

Comment: @Savner_Dig Haha, my very first upvote from one another user, thanks!